# Can't read xlsx file in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, xlrd

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
dirname = 'D:\SYun\BigData\DataScience-master\DataScience-master\data'
filename = '05. draw_korea_raw.xlsx'
path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
f = pd.read_excel(path)
print(f)
```

error:

```
raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

---

i downloaded pandas==1.1.5, xlrd==2.0.1, openpyxl==3.0.5, jupyter==1.0.0, python==3.8
and trying to collect excel data to make a graph but the code can't read xlsx file.
xls old excel version is fine but can't read new version of excel file. anyone knows how to solve this problem? or should i just use only xls data or convert to read the file.ㅠ.ㅠ

Comment: Please edit your question to be formatted properly. The title should be a title. Code should be code. Text should be text. Etc.

Comment: But your problem is likely that xlrd doesn't work with xlsx files and openpyxl must be used instead

Comment: are you sure that the xlsx exists in `D:\SYun\BigData\DataScience-master\DataScience-master\data\05. draw_korea_raw.xls`?

Comment: What's unclear about `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`?

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong error i edited it. it saying xlsx not supported, but when i googled other people works, but mine is not working. just want to know anyone has same problem like me and fix

Comment: The error message seems rather self-explanatory, can you be more specific as to what the issue is?

Comment: @AMC i want to read excel2016 file using pandas package. but it alarming 
--> 170         raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
    171 
    172     bk = open_workbook_xls(

XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported

Comment: @zoai Yes, I saw that in the post.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of xlrd(2.01) only supports .xls files. Installing the older version 1.2.0 may work to open .xlsx files.

Or to solve this, do the following:

1. Install [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/): This is another excel package that still supports the xlsx format
2. Set the engine to “openpyxl” instead of the default
   “xlrd”

   > ```
   > # Install openyxl
   > pip install openpyxl
   > # set engine parameter to "openpyxl"
   > pd.read_excel(path, engine = 'openpyxl')
   > ```

Comment: thank you #Islam. i tried as you said 1. putting r before the path and 2. simplified the path but still i get the problem "xlsx is not supported" so i decide to use openpyxl to open the file and view it with pandas DataFrame. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

tried many times to read xlsx file with pandas and xlrd. but i couldn't get the solution that i want. so i made a conclusion. the bast way is converting xlsx to xls 'OR' using openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('./06. result.xlsx')
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]

f = pd.DataFrame(sheet.values)
```

but this code makes NaN on the first column.

Comment: Saving my file in XLS format, instead of XLSX, did the trick. Many thanks!